# Unexpected multiple versions of Socket.dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

My C# project---a plugin for Rhino---shows the following strange behavior: after a while, it randomly stops compiling, with a compile-time error (shown in the editor too) on the call to `Socket.Receive()`.  The message (in french) translates to: A reference to the type 'Span<>' declares that it is defined in 'mscorlib', but cannot be found.

I can go to the definition of that symbol in Visual Studio (F12).  It shows the decompiled version of the Socket DLL.  However, it is not the same one works fine and when it no longer works.  When it works, the decompiled version shows no usage of the `Span<>` type; when it no longer works, the decompiled version shows it used at various places, including in some overloads of `Socket.Receive()`.  But the type `Span<>` is not defined anywhere.  I did not include `System.Memory` in my `.csproj` and I don't think I need to; I'm using `net48`.  FWIW, the decompiled version is full of this error wherever `Span<>` appears:

```
//IL_001b: Unknown result type (might be due to invalid IL or missing references)
```

I could fix the problem once by reinstalling Visual Studio from scratch.  That seems like an expensive workaround if it needs to be repeated every few days...  I am absolutely sure that it stopped working very suddenly, while I was working on the project, and not after any installing or uninstalling anything.  Version control says the .csproj and .sln files are unchanged.  I did add a new unrelated `.cs` file recently, so it may be related to that, though a mostly empty one so far.  (For some reason the list of `.cs` files does not show up in the the .csproj file, unlike what I'm used to in different projects.)

What I would like to understand is why Visual Studio suddenly picks up a different DLL for the `Socket` class.  How can I even know where that file is?  The decompiled version starts with `// emplacement inconnu`, i.e. unknown place.

Comment: Tried just now: threw away my whole tree of files and restored them from version control... problem fixed for now.  Previous attempt was to delete all files and folders listed in `.hgignore`: didn't help.  These two should have the same effect, but didn't.